# How to use Retrofit in android studio? and what is my problem?

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

i made interface like this in "TestService.java"

```
  public interface TestService {
        @GET("/api/users/2")
        Call<String> getTest();
    }
```

and

"RetrofitClient.java"

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private  static Retrofit instance;

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://reqres.in/")
                    .build();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

in "MainActivity.java"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofitClient = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
        TestService testService =  retrofitClient.create(TestService.class);
        Call<String> repos = testService.getTest(); //problem

    }
}
```

i'm first at android java, and i don't know how to use Retrofit..
what is the problem and how to print response? ( i need also header information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to asynchronously call it on the main thread.

```
    Call<ResponseBody> repos = testService.getTest();

    repos.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
           //response
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
           //error
        }
    });
```

There are plenty of resources online, to know more you can go through the following articles.

[vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

[android.jlelse](https://android.jlelse.eu/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-in-android-ed47aef01ecb)

Comment: `response.getHeaders()`